# how to refresh or redrawn the panel area again in windows forms application

Tags: vb.net, windows

I am using dynamically label with some text and images. I'm using them inside my loadflow function

Images which are onto the panel are loaded correctly and when I try to retrieve again after new DB call, images are not redrawn or refreshed.

I have tried already with some inbuilt functions like Invalidate, Refresh, Update but doesn't work at all.

My label with Image and Text looks as below

[image]

My code is

```
 Private Function LoadFlow()

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    'Check if datatable has rows and is not null
    If dtFlowPanel.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso dtFlowPanel IsNot Nothing Then


        cboCheckPointStatus.DataSource = dtFlowPanel
        cboCheckPointStatus.DisplayMember = "CHECKPOINTNAME"
        cboCheckPointStatus.ValueMember = "TERMINALCHECKPOINTID"


        UltraPanel1.Visible = True

        Do While (i < dtFlowPanel.Rows.Count)


            'CheckPointName Label
            lblCheckPointName = New Label
            lblCheckPointName.Text = dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("CHECKPOINTNAME").ToString()
            lblCheckPointName.Name = "CheckPoint"
            lblCheckPointName.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblCheckPointName.AutoSize = False
            lblCheckPointName.Height = 20
            lblCheckPointName.Width = 100
            lblCheckPointName.Location = New Point((i * 100), 50)

            'Round Circle Image Label
            lblImage1 = New Label
            lblImage1.Name = "Test" + i.ToString()
            lblImage1.Tag = i.ToString

            'If lblImage1.Name = "Test0" Then
            '    lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled1.png")
            'End If
            'If lblImage1.Name = "Test1" Then
            '    lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled1.png")
            'End If
            'If lblImage1.Name = "Test2" Then
            '    lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled2.png")
            'End If
            lblImage1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            lblImage1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            lblImage1.AutoSize = False
            lblImage1.Height = 20
            lblImage1.Width = 30
            lblImage1.Location = New Point((i * 100), 70)

            'Solid Black Line Image Label
            lblImage2 = New Label
            lblImage2.Name = "Test" + i.ToString()
            lblImage2.Tag = i.ToString

            lblImage2.Height = 20
            lblImage2.Width = 100
            lblImage2.Location = New Point((i * 100), 70)


            'Green Circle with Green Line
            If dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("Flag") = 0 Then
                lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled1.png")
                lblImage2.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Line1.png")
                'Yellow Circle with White Line
            ElseIf dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("Flag") = 1 Then
                lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled2.png")
                lblImage2.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Line.png")
                'Red Circle with White Line
            ElseIf dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("Flag") = 2 Then
                lblImage1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Untitled.png")
                lblImage2.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\Line.png")

            End If

            'DatePicker
            dtpicker = New DateTimePicker
            dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
            dtpicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
            dtpicker.ShowUpDown = True
            dtpicker.Height = 20
            dtpicker.Width = 95
            'horizontal
            dtpicker.Location = New Point((i * 100), 100)

            If Not IsDBNull(dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")) Then
                dtpicker.Value = dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")
            End If



            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(lblImage1)
            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(lblImage2)
            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(dtpicker)
            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(lblCheckPointName)

            lblImage1.Refresh()
            lblImage2.Refresh()

            i = (i + 1)

        Loop
    Else
        UltraPanel1.Visible = False
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're program is doing, but your problem:

```
lblImage1 = New Label
```

You don't have to create a new one, you can modify the existing label with your new image via `Image.FromFile` that you're already calling. If you load the image with that method, you don't even have to call `Refresh`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have fixed this issue

Comment: If Not lblImage1 Is Nothing Then
            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Remove(lblImage1)
        End If
        If Not lblImage2 Is Nothing Then
            Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Remove(lblImage2)
        End If

Comment: Added this If condition

Comment: Ah, okay. Glad you got it.